# How can i play the music from stopping point in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, audio-streaming, javasound

How can I continue play the music from stopping point and not from beginning in the method `ContinueMusic` that I wrote.

I stopped music in method `StopMusic`, but I want to continue from stopping point:

```
public class ui extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    public static void play()
    {
        try {      
            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D:\\sounds\\Calm music\\Condor.wav"));      
            format = stream.getFormat();      
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, stream.getFormat());      
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);         
            clip.open(stream);      
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }  
    } 
}

////////////////stop music///////////

private void StopMusicActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt) 
{            
    clip.close();
}

////////////start music again////////////////
private void ContinueMusicActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                                              
    play();
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    //////start////////
    play();

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() 
        {
            new ui().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where are `stream`, `format` and most importantly **`clip`** ever defined?  1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) **But basically, keep a reference to the `clip` &** ..

Comment: .. **call [`clip.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#start--).**

Comment: *"i stoped music in method StopMusic"* No! `clip.close();` ends all I/O & finalizes the clip. Stopping a clip playing is simply **`clip.stop();`** .. Always read the Java Docs for any method(s) in an example that does not run to expectation. If you have an IDE that links to docs, read them before selecting the 'auto complete'. That's what they are for. The art of 'programming by magic' fails 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Ok,,,thanks to all of you...

Comment: Ok,,,thanks to all of you...its working ,,i just call stop and start...thank you very much.

Comment: All of 'us' say.. glad you got it working. Now you might answer your own question below, or simply delete the question.